# jPlayer change playlist

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am doing an application with jPlayer. My idea is when radio buttons clicked the playlist changes. And I did it, but only works the first time that I clicked.

Then, I did alerts to see when script gets error and noticed in `jQuery_min("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer`.

```
jQuery_min("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            displayPlayList();
            playListInit(false); // Parameter is a boolean for autoplay.
        },
        oggSupport: false
    })
    .jPlayer("onProgressChange", function(loadPercent, playedPercentRelative, playedPercentAbsolute, playedTime, totalTime) {
        jpPlayTime.text(jQuery_min.jPlayer.convertTime(playedTime));
        jpTotalTime.text(jQuery_min.jPlayer.convertTime(totalTime));
    })
    .jPlayer("onSoundComplete", function() {
        playListNext();
    });
```

The first time that the script runs, it reads the previous function, else, it doesn't.

I tried this `jQuery_min("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("clearMedia");` and `jQuery_min("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("destroy");`  before the function, but no luck.

Thanks :)

And sorry my english, I am learning.

Comment: var jQuery_min = $.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

Use the Playlist add-on and change between playlist using the setPlaylist method.  More info can be found on the [Playlist Add-on](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) demo page on the jPlayer website.